# mod rewrite .htaccess query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^watch/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) watch.php?m=$1 [NC,L]
```

Okay, so I have this code in my `.htaccess` file, and the result I want to retrieve is:

- You can go to the url: `http://example.com/whateverhere/we're-a-website`
  without retrieving `Object not found`
- And the url: `http://example.com/whateverhere/this-is-Bat-Man`
  What I want to retrieve with the second url, is that in my database, the title would say: `Bat-Man` and not `Bat Man`, so I want it to show `-` even if it already was in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[a-z]` means only match a - z

`[A-Z]`  means only match A - Z

`[0-9]` means only match 0 - 9

`[-_]` means only match - or _

Combined together `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]` matches only those characters.  So if you don't really want to limit to those characters, use `.` which matches any character.

```
RewriteRule ^watch/(.+) watch.php?m=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What's the plus sign there for?

Comment: You really need to lookup "regex" and learn the syntax, but basically `+` means it can repeat 1 or more times.